# Running Ant in Sphinx4

Tags: java, ant

I am PG student and started working on Sphinx4 for my Voice to Speech conversion project and I followed the instructions as they gave in **index.html** file of Sphinx4 folder.
After running the commands

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_14
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/apache-ant-1.8.0
export PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_10/bin:/usr/local/apache-ant 1.8.0/bin:$PATH
```

I am trying to run **ant** command, it shows some errors like this

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
We cannot execute /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_14/bin/java
```

Can anyone help me to solve this error which wll really helps me to continue my work further.
Thank You.

Comment: Can you post the result of the command `env|sort`. Please update the question with your result. Also define `export CLASSPATH=$ANT_HOME/lib:$CLASSPATH`. And what is the result of command `ls -l /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_14/bin/java`

Comment: The above command gives like this sir,                                                        ls: cannot access /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_14/bin/java: No such file or directory

Comment: Please use the right java path and user has privileged to execute.